# How to configure LUIS response when there will be no match found in KB QnA maker using Node.js?

Tags: azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker

Not able to figure out how to initiate the dialogue when there is no match found on KB.
With that dialog, I need to configure the LUIS response.
I am using this sample https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/49.qnamaker-all-features.

Comment: Are you wanting to make the no KB match dialog show or are you wanting to configure the message inside the no KB match dialog? If it is the later then you could configure the `noAnswer` variable on line 31 to use the global `DefaultNoAnswer` in the same file (not the one from `ActivityFactory` inside the qnamakerBaseDialog file. See [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/49.qnamaker-all-features/dialogs/qnamakerBaseDialog.js#L31).

Answer (score 0):

As you are navigating the example: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/49.qnamaker-all-features

You can easily go to "dialog" - > Then "qnamakerBaseDialog.js"

You can see the var "noAnswer"

What you need to do is to customize the value then you should see what you want.